# What happens to those parts of the amplitude that are not inside the black hole?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, waves, black-holes, frequency

Assuming that a sinusoidal wave with an amplitude a million times bigger than the diameter of a black hole enters a black hole, what happens to those parts of the amplitude that are not inside the black hole?

The other question I have is, "Does the black hole change the amplitude of a frequency that enters it?"

Comment: A wave in what medium/field? If you're talking about an electromagnetic wave (for example), its amplitude has nothing to do with the size of the black hole - it's not like a water wave where the amplitude is in space . In the electromagnetic wave the amplitude is the magnitude of the electric and magnetic fields. So it's not clear why or how you want to compare this amplitude - in units volts per meter - to the size of the black hole (units of meter).

Comment: @Nadav Har'El I was talking about  an electromagnetic wave; so does the black hole change the amplitude of an electromagnetic wave that enters it?

Comment: I think you are asking a very specific question which doesn't mean what you think it means. The wave's **amplitude** is not a length and is unrelated to the black hole's diameter. When the wave comes near the black hole, the curved space-time begins to change the wave, but not specifically its amplitude. The wave will never actually "enter" the black hole or even its horizon - it will experience gravitational red-shifting (which affects the frequency, not amplitude) and time dilation and will never actually reach the horizon from outsiders' point of view.

Comment: See Rayleigh scattering theory for the cross section of absorbers that are much smaller than the wavelength.

Comment: It's possible the OP means wavelength, not amplitude

Answer (score 1):

> what happens to those parts of the amplitude that are not inside the black hole ?

I am not completely sure what you mean by "parts of the amplitude". However, from the point of view of a distant external observer, the wave never enters the black hole - due to time dilation it is increasingly red-shifted as it approaches (but never reaches) the event horizon.

Answer (score 0):

Gravitons are massless particles, like photons. So they follow the same paths that photons do (the technical term is "null geodesic"). Since photons cannot escape the event horizon of a black hole, gravitons can't either.

However, gravitons don't actually need to escape a black hole in order for you to detect its gravity. The gravity you feel at a particular point in spacetime is determined by the local curvature of spacetime at that point. Therefore, you don't need to know what's going on inside the black hole in order to feel the curvature of spacetime outside it.

(Important remark: The picture of gravitons as the "mediators" of gravity, like photons are the mediators of the electromagnetic interaction, is actually incorrect. Unlike the electromagnetic interaction, gravity is fundamentally nonlinear. But gravitons are the quanta of linearized gravity, which means they are only suitable for describing very weak gravitational fields, such as gravitational waves.

Black holes are, obviously, the complete opposite of weak and therefore a description of them using gravitons is inadequate.nonlinear gravity is, and that is in fact one of the things a full theory of quantum gravity must be able to explain.)